# How can draw this widget with use flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform

I have just started to learn flutter and ı am stucked . I have column but ı couldnt divide with autlo responsive desing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeEv8.png) How can ı draw this component with Flutter.
Thanks for help..

Use Expanded with column and ı gave spesifix flex point but it didnt work

Comment: Hi there, try to include the image (not only the link). That image has an ugly quality, try another one.

Comment: Hi, your image is not clear, please tell us the exact thing you want to make a widget

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment parameters of Column and try to give specific height for Column wrapping Container or SizedBox widget.